# Game Center crashes in simulator with iOS prior to version 4.1

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, game-center

After I added Game Center, the app crashes at start up, in simulator with iOS prior to version 4.1. Haven't check it in real devices yet. (Hard to find one.)

I added '-weak-lSystem' option to the link flags as answers to other questions said, but it didn't work.

How to walk around this? Or I shouldn't care about that at all?

Comment: game center isn't available before 4.1. have you weak linked the game center framework? are you making calls to game center?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Now I solved the issue by weak link the GameKit framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close it: weak link the GameKit framework will do. Then the app will not crash on devices with iOS prior to version 4.1.